# Magento 2:i18n folder to custom theme

Tags: magento2, localisation, core, extend, file

I want to edit **.csv** file in module-wishlist to my custom theme.

I have copied the the file from module-wishlist and copied to

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Wishlist/i18n/en_US.csv.

But not working. Please help.

Comment: please let me know if you have query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When you have to override transalation file from core module into your theme,**
You have to keep its inside theme **i18n** Folder,

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Just run command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

clear cache.

Comment: If your store locale is not en_US then deploy with locale.
Example for en_GB : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB