# Remove "items" text in wishlist

Tags: theme, magento2.2.3

I am new to Magento 2 and been wondering how to remove wishlist counter text.

I had tried generating a language pack using this command:

```
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv" app/design/frontend/vendor/theme
```

in the newly generated files with **2 columns**, I changed

```
%1 items
```

to

```
%1
```

I also tried replicating the one on Magento_Wishlist then put it in my custom theme but it does not work either.

Also, I tried this [accepted solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177992/magento-2i18n-folder-to-custom-theme) but still no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: do you need to remove from header dropdown ?

Comment: @hweb87 No. I repositioned my Wishlist but I didn't remove any of its elements. I just wanted to remove the text in the counter because I will style it as a badge(like facebook notification count).

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with [Daniele](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/56832/daniele-rovatti) that it is better to use translation dictionary, it is useful to know other possible methods:

– you can override **createCounter** function in *Vendor/Module/CustomerData/Wishlist.php*

```
/**
* Create button label based on wishlist item quantity
*
* @param int $count
* @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase|null
*/
protected function createCounter($count)
{
    return $count;
}
```

– you can update link template ( by default it is *view/frontend/templates/link.phtml* ) and change

`<span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span>`

to

`<span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')" class="counter qty"></span>`

Comment: more wishlist tips and tricks - https://nwdthemes.com/2019/08/23/magento-2-working-with-wishlist/

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this :

```
"%1 items","%1"
```

Then clear cache and deploy :

```
php bin/magento clear:cache
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I already did that but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify the module in your language pack?

Like this

```
"%1 items","%1",module,Magento_Wishlist
```

Then flush cache and reload your page

Comment: I haven't tried that since the csv file that was generated only has 2 columns and I don't know which module does each phrases belong.

Answer (score 0):

I already figured out how to remove "items" in wishlist counter.

Instead of modifying the translation pack, I extended

```
Magento/Wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist
```

to my custom module then override the function **createCounter()**, remove the text "items" in "%1 items"

```
protected function createCounter($count)
    {
        if ($count > 1) {
            return __('%1', $count);
        } elseif ($count == 1) {
            return __('1');
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update template File `view/frontend/templates/link.phtml`

From

```
<span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter" class="counter qty"></span>
```

TO

```
<span data-bind="text: wishlist().counter.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '')" class="counter qty"></span>
```